# Vlc.DotNet.Core taking snapshot while streaming

Tags: c#, video-streaming, snapshot, libvlc

I am using Vlc.DotNet.Core for multicast video streaming. Also, I want to take snapshots. For testing, I am working on a simple program that calling snapshot function for every 2 seconds. However snapshot function is not working, when `TakeSnapshot` function called, it is not calling `OnMediaPlayerSnapshotTaken` event.

Besides that, I made a snapshot tests for `Vlc.DotNet.Forms` library and its working quite well.

The simple code I am working on is given below :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using Vlc.DotNet.Core;

namespace SnapshotTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VlcStreamerSnapshotText myObject = new VlcStreamerSnapshotText();

            myObject.streamFile();
        }
    }
    class VlcStreamerSnapshotText
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        static Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

        public bool streamFile(string source = "")
        {
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 2000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var libDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "x86" : "x64"));

            var options = new string[]
            {
                "--no-snapshot-preview",
                "--no-audio"
                //"--no-video"
                // VLC options can be given here. Please refer to the VLC command line documentation.
        };

            mediaPlayer = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer(new DirectoryInfo(libDirectory.FullName), options);

            string[] mediaOptions = new string[]
            {
                ":sout=#duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://127.0.0.1:1000/},dst=display}",
                ":sout-all",
                ":sout-keep"
            };

            //string[] mediaOptions = new string[] { string.Concat("--sout=#duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://", IpAddress, ":", "1000", "/}} --sout-all --sout-keep") };

            mediaPlayer.SetMedia(new Uri("http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_h264.mov"), mediaOptions);

            mediaPlayer.SnapshotTaken += OnMediaPlayerSnapshotTaken;

            bool playFinished = false;
            mediaPlayer.PositionChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.Write("\r" + Math.Floor(e.NewPosition * 100) + "%");
            };

            mediaPlayer.EncounteredError += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.Error.Write("An error occurred");
                playFinished = true;
            };

            mediaPlayer.EndReached += (sender, e) =>
            {
                playFinished = true;
            };

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => mediaPlayer.Play());
            //mediaPlayer.Play();

            // Ugly, sorry
            while (!playFinished)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
            }
            return true;
        }

        ManualResetEvent m_mreSnapshot = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private readonly object m_snapLock = new object();
        private bool m_SnapshotIsTaken = false;
        public bool GetSnapshot()
        {
            m_SnapshotIsTaken = false;
            if (mediaPlayer == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
            string uniqueId = generateID(string.Empty);
            string snapName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.png", currentTime, uniqueId);

            string tempFilePathCand = Path.GetTempPath();

            if (!tempFilePathCand.EndsWith("\\"))
                tempFilePathCand = tempFilePathCand + "\\" + snapName;
            else
                tempFilePathCand = tempFilePathCand + snapName;

            FileInfo snapPathInfo = new FileInfo(tempFilePathCand);
            //mediaPlayer.Manager.TakeSnapshot();
            mediaPlayer.TakeSnapshot(snapPathInfo);

            m_mreSnapshot.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            if (m_SnapshotIsTaken)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        private string generateID(string tip)
        {
            return string.Format(@"{0}_{1}", tip, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        }

        void OnMediaPlayerSnapshotTaken(object sender, VlcMediaPlayerSnapshotTakenEventArgs e)
        {
            mediaPlayer.SnapshotTaken -= OnMediaPlayerSnapshotTaken;
            m_SnapshotIsTaken = true;
            mediaPlayer.SnapshotTaken += OnMediaPlayerSnapshotTaken;
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetSnapshot();
        }
    }
}
```

So, What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bug in Vlc.DotNet: https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/447 
Are you using Vlc.DotNet v3?

Comment: Also tested on Vlc.DotNet v3.0 however still the same